# Qt - setting relative mouse position

Tags: qt

I'm moving my graphics engine from Freeglut to Qt. My window class inherits from QWindow. 
I have a problem with setting relative mouse position to the center of the window and hiding a cursor.
In freeglut the code looks like this:

```
glutWarpPointer((glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2), (glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2));
glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
```

I was trying something like this:

```
this->cursor().setPos((width() / 2), (height() / 2)); // this seems to set an absolute (global) position
this->cursor().setShape(Qt::BlankCursor); // doesn't work
```

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any effect, because you're editing a temporary copy.
 Look at at the signature: `QCursor QWidget::cursor() const`. The cursor object is returned by value.
To apply cursor changes, you must pass the modified object back via `setCursor()`. To map from local to global coordinates, use `mapToGlobal()`:

```
QCursor c = cursor();
c.setPos(mapToGlobal(QPoint(width() / 2, height() / 2)));
c.setShape(Qt::BlankCursor);
setCursor(c);
```